# Finding the coefficients of a polynomial $P(x)$ with non-negative integral coefficients if $P(n)=k$ is given.

Tags: polynomials

I read about this method in a blog on AoPS. Check the question on the blog [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c573402h1690700).

The question says let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with non negative integer coefficients such that $P(0)=33$, $P(1)=40$ and $P(9)=60000$. Find $P(2)$.

I know this question is already asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530183/given-a-polynomial-p-with-integer-coefficients-find-p2).

My question is based on the method they showed to solve this question.
They first found $a_0 =33$ and that each of the coefficients must be less than $9$ (except for $a_0$). Then they converted $60000 -33$ into base $9$ and equated each coefficient with the digits of this number, which makes sense.

Suppose we want to find the polynomial $g(x)$ with non negative integer coefficients such that $g(2)=2017$ and $g(5)=2002$. I tried to use the same method but by converting $2017$ to base $2$, I got a different set of coefficients than what I got after converting $2002$ to base $5$. What is the mistake that I'm making / why is the method not applicable here?

Comment: Polynomials with non negative coefficients are increasing on the positive numbers and yours is not so no solution

Comment: @Conrad Oh! yes. That is correct. However, if I were to say $g(2)=2002$ and $g(5)=2017$ , even then I would get a different set of integers as the coefficients. What goes wrong there?